# Python regex positive look ahead

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex that is supposed to find sequence of words that are ended with a punctuation. The look ahead function assures that after the match there is a space and a capital letter or digit.

```
pat1 = re.compile(r"\w.+?[?.!](?=\s[A-Z\d])"
```

What is the function of the following lookahead?

```
pat2 = re.compile(r"\w.+?[?.!](?=\s+[A-Z\d])"
```

Is Python 3.2 supporting variable lookahead (\s+)? I do not get any error. Furthermore I cannot see any differences in both patterns. Both seem to work the same regardless the number of blanks that I have. Is there an explanation for the purpose of the \s+  in the look ahead?

Comment: Sorry somehow my question got messed up.

Comment: You are still missing closing round brakets!

Comment: You should post some examples of string that you expect to use, and how exactly you search/match/find them with the re module

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the first lookahead expects **exactly** one whitespace character before the digit or capital letter while the second one expects **at least one** whitespace character but as many as possible.

The + is called a quantifier. It means 1 to n as many as possible.

To recap

```
\s (Exactly one whitespace character allowed. Will fail without it or with more than one.)
\s+ (At least one but maybe more whitespaces allowed.)
```

[Further studying.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

```
I have multiple blanks, the \w.+? continues to match the blanks until the last blank before the capital letter
```

To answer this comment please consider :

What does \w.+? actually matches?

A **single** word character [a-zA-Z0-9_] followed by at least one "any" character(except newline) but with the **lazy** quantifier +?. So in your case, it leaves one space so that the lookahead later matches. Therefore you consume all the blanks except one. This is why you see them at your output.

Comment: Thanks FailedDev.  When I run the regex with only \s and I have multiple blanks, the \w.+? continues to match the blanks until the last blank before the capital letter. In my result I am getting a text with blanks like :"the car is parked----","in the garage"(--symbolizes blanks). If I have the \s+ in the lookahead, the extra blanks are not captured and I get "the car is parked","in the garage". Regardless how many blanks I have in between the words. Is it correct that python 3 is supporting variable look ahead?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you are tying to achieve here.

Sequence of words ended by a punctuation can be matched with something like:

```
re.findall(r'([\w\s]*[\?\!\.;])', s)
```

the lookahead requires another string to follow?

In any case:

- \s requires *one and only one* space;
- \s+ requires *at least* one space.

And yes, the lookahead accepts the "+" modifier even in python 2.x

The same as before but with a lookahead:

```
re.findall(r'([\w\s]*[\?\!\.;])(?=\s\w)', s)
```

or

```
re.findall(r'([\w\s]*[\?\!\.;])(?=\s+\w)', s)
```

you can try them all on something like:

```
s='Stefano ciao.   a domani. a presto;'
```

Depending on your strings, the lookahead might be necessary or not, and might or might not change to have "+" more than one space option.